# PHP Strings split in to divs but sometimes words split

Tags: php, string, split

So the idea is I eventually have data displayed from a database formatted in a magazine style. I want a string to be split into columns, but without using css3's columns feature due to its incompatibility in certain browsers.

I've got quite far stopping and starting the string in a new div, where it left off, and obviously later I'd have pagination stuff, but for the moment I've got some of my words split in two when it splits into another div. This shouldn't happen, though, as I followed some instructions on another page here which should have stopped the words splitting so I dunno what's going on. Wondering if you guys can help. [Here](http://psltranslation.com/sites/mag/view.php) is the page:

Here is the PHP file "./data/lost.php" where the strings are temporarily being pulled from (shortened the body string, for here, though, as you get the idea):

```
<?php
$title = "This is where the title will go...";
$username = "[Full Name]";
$date = "[Creation Date]";
$body = 'The first season begins with a plane crash that leaves the surviving passengers of Oceanic Airlines Flight 815 on what seems to be a deserted tropical island. Their survival is threatened by a number of mysterious entities, including polar bears, an unseen creature that roams the jungle (the "Smoke Monster"), and the island\'s malevolent inhabitants known as "the Others"...';
$quote = '"This is a space reserved for a quote..."';

?>
```

Here is the php for the page:

```
    <?php

require_once('./data/lost.php');

function text($text,$limit,$length)
{
$newbody = substr($text, $length, strpos(wordwrap($text, $limit), "\n"));

global $newlength;
$newlength = ($length + strlen($newbody));

return $newbody;
};

echo "

<div id='wrapper'>
            <div id='articlecont'>
                    <div id='title'>". $title ."</div>
                    <div class='col12'>
                        <div id='artimage'>An Image will go here...</div>
                        <div class='col1'><span style='font-size:0.8em;'>Author: ". $username ." on: ". $date ."</span><br />
<br />". text($body,495, 0) ."</div>
                            <div class='col2'>". text($body,520, $newlength) ."</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='col22'>
                            <div class='col31'>". text($body,390, $newlength) ."</div>
                        <div class='quote'>". $quote ."</div>
                        <div class='col32'>". text($body,260, $newlength) ."</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='col4'>". text($body,3000, $newlength) ."</div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </body>
</html>";

?>
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide. I will keep checking back for a response.

Answer (score 0):

check your `substr()` arguments , the second parameter is start , third is length

‎[substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Comment: Thanks Yeah, I looked over it but it seems right.

$text is my body string, $length is the position where the it will start from (maybe just didn't give it a good name but it was my logic at the time) and the $limit is how many characters I want it to pull.

I can't see what's wrong with it. Any other suggestions?